# WordPress multi-page recurring payment form

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, checkout, recurring-billing, foxycart

I'm trying to make a recurring subscription for monthly and annual basis. The idea is there will be two pages. Page one will be the selection process for the subscription and page two is checkout page with billing information.

I'm trying to do this for past several days. I have foxycart account. It would be best if I can use this as checkout. I will use paypal, credit-card and iDeal as Payment gateway.

If anyone has done this sort of work, I need the guideline how to do it or if there is any plugin which is best for this kind of project.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to customize your checkout, you actually only need 1 page since FoxyCart handles the checkout process for you.

FoxyCart handles subscriptions automatically of for you and can handle both PayPal and other forms of payment.

If you log into your account, the last item in your settings menu is 'sample code'. There are instructions for getting the necessary files, and an example item to add to a cart.

While I don't have experience with subscriptions, here is there documentation on recurring billing.

https://wiki.foxycart.com/v/2.0/products/subscriptions

All in all, FC is very easy to setup and is extensively customizable with some time and patience.